# How can I use custom methods inside a T4 template which resides in another assembly

Tags: visual-studio, t4

I have a dll called utilities which contains some helper methods and I want to use one of the helper methods inside a T4 template like <#=tbl.ClassName.ToProper()#>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use [assembly](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-assembly-directive/) and [import](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-import-directive/) directives to reference your dll and the namespace where your helper class is defined.